# Account forgot password handle

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1

I am using the layout handle `customer_account` to add CSS to the account pages like this:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <name>css/parts/account.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

But it seems that this CSS is not added to the `forgot password` page, while it does have the same type of url as the other account pages: `domain.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/`

My question: **What is the layout handle for this page**, or is there a way to add this page to the `customer account` handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customer_account` handle is only used for logged in account pages:

- Customer Dashboard
- Customer Account Edit
- Customer Address
- Customer Address Form
- Customer Downloadable Products
- Customer Newsletter Subscriptions
- Customer OAuth applications
- Customer Product Reviews
- Customer Product Reviews Details
- Customer Order History
- Customer Order View
- Customer Invoice View
- Customer Shipment View
- Customer Creditmemo View
- Customer Reorder
- Customer Tags List
- Customer Tag View
- Customer Wishlist
- Customer Wishlist Sharing Form
- Customer Billing Agreements
- Customer Billing Agreements View
- Customer Recurring Profile
- Customer Recurring Profile View
- Customer Recurring Profiler Orders

The handle for the forgot password page is `customer_account_forgotpassword`

Comment: Weird... The Customer Login page is also used for the customer_account handle. Oh well, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen out of the box, the `customer_account` handle is not used for the customer login page. It sounds like it's coming from a custom layout.

Comment: Huh? That's weird. I just made a custom CSS file, account.css and added it via the layout code above. Every change I made there, appeared at the login page

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen search for `<update handle="customer_account"/>` in your layout files ;)